# z-index > css background-img > absolute img > p tag

Tags: html, css

how to put my p tag above all?

here's my code

```
HTML
    <section class="key-fundamentals">
        <div class="container">
        <img class="img-man-cbox img-responsive" src="images/img-man-cbox.png">
            <p>Our key fundamentals</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.key-fundamentals {
 z-index: -999;
 height: 535px;
 background-image: url('../images/bg-fundamentals.png');
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.key-fundamentals .img-man-cbox {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 782px;
  left: 80px;
}
.key-fundamentals p{
 z-index: 2;
 color: red;
}
```

h1 tag is below img2 image absolute 
when i put zindex -1 to img2 the image will disappear.

please help.. thanks!

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Could you post some real code rather than that weird pseudo code?

Comment: Update your question to a proper one, and you'll get a proper answer

Comment: i just update my code.. please check thanks

Comment: @FReyes Thanks for correcting your snippet. Are you sure you're not posting a `LESS`/`SASS` because that's not a valid `CSS` syntax

Comment: yes this is SASS i will update.. wait

Comment: i just update my code.. please check thanks...

Comment: @FReyes I don't see any `H1` tag, so perhaps the selector should be `.key-fundamentals p {` instead of `.key-fundamentals h1{`?

Comment: @AlonEitan sorry i just updated.. please check again.. sorry a lot... check again please.

Comment: @FReyes I've just created an example with random images from imgur (https://jsfiddle.net/azaqqyyg/) but LGSon was faster :) So accept their answer if it helped you

Comment: @AlonEitan thanks a lot sir!

Answer (score 2):

For `z-index` to work, the element need a position other than `static`

```
.key-fundamentals p {
 position: relative;         /*  added property  */
 z-index: 2;
 color: red;
}
```

```css
.key-fundamentals {
  z-index: -999;
  height: 535px;
  background-image: url('../images/bg-fundamentals.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.key-fundamentals .img-man-cbox {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.key-fundamentals p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="key-fundamentals">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="img-man-cbox img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150/ddd">
    <p>Our key fundamentals</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @FReyes Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept?